# MediaPlayer mutes after some minutes of playing mp3

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm developing an AudioBook player for Android. For the playing part, I've used `MediaPlayer` class which works perfectly for some minutes but then always suddenly fails and no voice could be heard.

Even if I stop and issue a new request (read new chapter) it doesn't work. However the passing of time seems natural (for example playing a 10 seconds clip takes 10 seconds to finish) but there is absolutely no voice!

Does someone have any clues what might cause this problem?

[Here's the relevant parts of my `MediaPlayer` usage](http://pastebin.com/uZ61NYmP).
[And here's the logcat around the place it mutes](http://pastebin.com/gLfxL3wh).

**EDIT:**
By analyzing the logcat, I found out that this part is showing after the muting has happened:

```
E/AudioFlinger(  146): no more track names available
E/AudioTrack(  146): AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
E/AudioSink(  146): Unable to create audio track
E/AwesomePlayer(  146): deleting Audio Player - start failed
E/MediaPlayer( 5558): error (-19, 0)
***V/MainActivity( 5558): onNewPage()
E/MediaPlayer( 5558): Error (-19,0)
E/Sensors (  285): sensors_poll_context_t::pollEvents, line 202: receive event #### i=2, nb=0
E/Sensors (  285): sensors_poll_context_t::pollEvents, line 202: receive event #### i=2, nb=0
E/Sensors (  285): sensors_poll_context_t::pollEvents, line 202: receive event #### i=2, nb=0
E/Sensors (  285): sensors_poll_context_t::pollEvents, line 202: receive event #### i=2, nb=0
***V/MediaPlayerWrapper( 5558): stop()
***D/MediaPlayerWrapper( 5558): Stopping player...
E/MediaPlayer( 5558): stop called in state 0
E/MediaPlayer( 5558): error (-38, 0)
```

The lines with three * at beginning are my messages, others are frameworks'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simply because of not releasing the media player object; as these answers ([a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9888612/1385489),[b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16099899/1385489),[c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17124617/1385489)) suggested already.

```
mMediaPlayer.release();
```